# Google Developer OAuth Consent: The supplied API key is not configured for use from this referrer

Tags: javascript, api, calendar, google-api

I'm trying to play around a little bit with the Google Calendar API but I can't create a OAuth ID ( as mentioned in this example: [Google Calendar JS API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js).

I created a project, clicked Cerdentials and if you try to create an OAutho-client-Id you will be forwarded to the configure  consent tab.

Here you have to enter your email address (is standard google account) and a project name. Then pressing save leads to an error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The supplied API key is not configured for use from this referrer.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
         {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/648364020234/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The URL metioned in this JSON I can't access (no rights). 
What can I do to get a simple oAuth ID?

Tried with several new projects, other naming of the consent projet name. 
Also tried to create an API key which can be referred by all clients (empty field).

Any ideas anybody?

Comment: I do not think there is a "simple" oAuth, you would need to add them, If I remember right it is a comma separated list.

Comment: Where should this be: 
You can select new credentials, options are: API-Key, OAuth-Client-ID and  Service account Key. If you select OAuth-Client-ID you will be forwarded to the consent screen with a note, that you have to add consent information before a OAuth-Id can be generated. And then you can only add a name and some optional website information (help site etc.). After adding a name -> Save -> error occurs